# How to prevent assigning an event listener multiple times to an element when using Click Outside hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There are many versions of the click outside hooks out there that will attach a "mousedown" or "touchstart" event listener to the document and close a dropdown or modal window when you click outside...

The problem is if you have many dropdowns using the same hook you end up with the same events attached to the document multiple times.

How to prevent that? and does it matter as long as you remove them when you unmount the components?

I've already researched and there doesn't seem to be a way to check whether a dom element already has an event attached to it.

An example taken from: [useOnClickOutside](https://usehooks.com/useOnClickOutside/)

```
const useOnClickOutside = (ref, handler) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = event => {
      // Do nothing if clicking ref's element or descendent elements
      if (!ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }
      handler(event);
    };

    const escape = event => {
      if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        handler(event);
      }
    };

    // these event listeners pile up on the document if you have several component using that hook
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', listener);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', listener);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', escape, false);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', listener);
      document.removeEventListener('touchstart', listener);
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', escape);
    };
  }, [ref, handler]);
};
```

Here using that hook on 5 different dropdowns on the page, assigns the same event listener 5 times to the document

[image]

Comment: You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? Since the `listener` needs a user-defined `handler` param. 
Unless you are passing the same `handler` function in all the dropdowns, you need to worry about it.

Comment: @Prabusamvel I'm concerned that it can have an impact on performance, though unlikely unless you have thousands of dropdown instances, the thing is that it triggers the callback as many times as there are listeners. Not worried about memory leaks since I remove the listeners on unmount but though that perhaps there is a way of avoiding it as it is unnecessary and redundant. that's all

Comment: @Fabrice I can understand your point. My suggestion is instead of attaching the event on the dropdown mount. You can do it on dropdown open and remove it on dropdown close. It's fact that only one dropdown is going to be open at a time. So you will end up with that one event.

Answer (score 4):

The best practice to do this is using [useEffect cleanup function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/using-useeffect-in-react-js-functional-component#:%7E:text=Inside%20useEffect%20we%20can%20add,function%20does%20the%20cleanup%20work.&text=Adding%20return%20statement%20is%20optional,depends%20upon%20the%20use%20cases.)

```
const handleMouseDown = e => {
  console.log(e)
} 

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown)
  // cleanup
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown)
  }
}, [])
```

By passing the empty array `[]` to the `useEffect` you guarantee that the event listeners are registered only in the initial mounting of the component. By using the cleanup function, you avoid registering it more than once.

Comment: yes I agree but that doesn't prevent from attaching the mousedown listener several times over if you have multiple elements using the hook

Comment: Can you post your code, or a `codesandbox`?

Answer (score 0):

if we are calling this component multiple times then in that case also on each and every mount event will be attached to the document.

Possible to write useEffect with event listener on top of the component and call handler method from anywhere then it won't happen.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32748627)